# The field 'Fieldname' must be max length of '20'. 'Fieldname' in SQL is nvarchar(450)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When trying to read a 'Fieldname' in the database it throws an error stating the maximum length exceeds 20.

But the sql column has a max length of 450. What's the cause of this?

I can solve this by adding attribute[MaxLength(450)] to my model property, but I'd still like to know the "WHY" too.

Note: I am using Entity Framework with Diagram-first approach.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? If you are, are you using it with code-first approach or diagram-first approach? If it is diagram-first and you made some changes on the actual DB, it won't update the diagram and models unless you say it to do, and it may cause this kind of problems.

Comment: @ycansener that was the issue. thank you kindly.

Comment: you're very welcome.